# Make a list out of variables

Tags: python, list, variables

This is part of my script:

```
for line in range(0,len(lines),2):
        num = lines[line].split()[8]
        num1= abs(num)
```

Obviously I can produce many num1 here from each line....

Here I want to put all these num1 into one list, then how can I do? thx

Sorry guys, this is python! lol

Comment: It's a good idea to specify what language you're using.

Comment: BTW does your code actually work? `abs(int(num))` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
newlist.add(num1)
```

What language are you trying to do this in?

Comment: solution for an unknown language. that's nice.

Answer (score 4):

```
li = []
for line in range(0,len(lines),2):
        num = lines[line].split()[8]
        li.append(abs(num))
```

or

```
li = [abs(lines[line].split()[8]) for line in range(0,len(lines),2)]
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `line` counter. Couldn't you do `[abs(line.split()[8]) for i,line in enumnerate(lines) if not i%2]`
instead?

Answer (score 0):

In Python, we iterate directly. You want items from the list of lines, so ask for items of the list of lines. Don't ask for numeric indices and then index into the list.

Since we want every other line, the simplest way to do that is to just 'slice' the list.

We can build up the list of results by using a list comprehension. Don't waste your breath telling Python how to put things together into a list. Just tell it what should be included.

Oh, and as noted, the list contains strings, and chopping it up produces more strings, and we can't apply `abs` to a string. We need to convert the result explicitly first.

```
result = [abs(int(line.split()[8])) for line in lines[::2]]
```